# How to set Facebook uploaded videos to play as "HD" by default?

Tags: video, facebook

When I upload a video to Facebook (not from Youtube, an actual video file), the Facebook player has a setting to play it back in "HD" via a button in the lower right hand corner of the player. Is it possible to get this "HD" setting to be the default when people click on the video? I was not able to find anything online regarding this, except [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120128225405AAIvkc2) which doesn't even work (for me at least, I'm using Chrome if that makes any difference).

Comment: Settings > Videos > Video Default Quality > HD if available

You're welcome!

Comment: Wellll...I think that's only for viewing videos for yourself on your own account. This still doesn't solve how to set how it shows for others who watch a video I uploaded. The reason still being gronostaj's answer cited below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Also note that not everybody has a network connection that allows to watch HD videos comfortably.

Comment: I realize this answer is old. I was waiting to see if anyone had alternatives. Thank you for the info.

Comment: It is definitely possible all the videos uploaded on GoPro facebook page play in HD by default. I just don't know how to do that.